# Mac OSX sed - removing a string containing a dot from multiple files

Tags: sed, osx

Trying to remove a string across multiple files in a directory with sed. The folder contains a large amount of sql files, all with table names that I need to remove. For instance, one of the files looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO staging.eav_attribute_set (attribute_set_id, entity_type_id, attribute_set_name, sort_order) VALUES (1, 1, 'Default', 2);
INSERT INTO staging.eav_attribute_set (attribute_set_id, entity_type_id, attribute_set_name, sort_order) VALUES (2, 2, 'Default', 2);
INSERT INTO staging.eav_attribute_set (attribute_set_id, entity_type_id, attribute_set_name, sort_order) VALUES (3, 3, 'Default', 1);
INSERT INTO staging.eav_attribute_set (attribute_set_id, entity_type_id, attribute_set_name, sort_order) VALUES (4, 4, 'Default', 1);
```

I need to remove `staging.` from all lines. I've tried the following from the directory where the files are:

```
sed -i 's/staging.//g' *
sed -i 's/staging\.//g' *
sed -i 's|staging.||g' *
```

But receive the following:

```
sed: 1: "eav_attribute_set ...": unterminated substitute pattern
```

Comment: Hmmm... That error message does not correspond in any way to the commands that you've been trying.

Comment: your tag states "osx" but your title states "Linux". Their `sed` implementations are different, which one are you using?

Comment: I'm using macos terminal. I've updated my question/title. Good eyes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With FreeBSD `sed` (as found on macOS), you need:

```
sed -i '' 's/staging\.//g' ./*
```

Answer (score 0):

This going to remove `staging.` in your file.

```
cat ${yourfile} | sed 's/staging\.//g' > tmp && mv tmp ${yourfile}
```

Comment: That unescaped `.` will match any character.